# STYLEREF "Headline 2" reporting also the number above

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes, numbering

I have a numbered list with 2 levels:

```
1 Title
...
2 Title
2.1 Title: I want #1
...
2.2 Title: I want #2
3 Title
```

My target is to get automatically the correct number after #
I tried using:

```
STYLEREF "Headline 2" \n
```

but I get "2.1" instead of just "1"
and "2.2" instead of just "2"

how can I solve this?
Could I modified the field to remove the 2 first characters? or there is a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### The simplest way is to change your multilevel list numbering so that the second level does not have the number from above.

The [StyleRef Field](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF) is working as designed. It does not have switches to further pare the number.

**You can use an calculation field in your header** but it will not update as automatically but should update upon printing or print  preview. This uses the `\# .0` switch to give you the decimal part and then multiplies it by 10 to get an integer. This will only work with level 2.

```
{ = { StyleRef "Headline 2" \n \# .0 } * 10 }
```